# go over a list of files in a directory

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a Perl script that receive a file and a path to a directory,
The directory contains files that are links to other directories.
I want to go over the files in the directory one by one,
And for each file search the file name at my input file and replace it with the address its linked to

For example, if the script received the directory `"/myworkspace/mydir"`
That contain the following file:

```
myfile1  ->  /myworkspace/globaldir/file1
myfile2  ->  /myworkspace/somedir/file2
myfile3  ->  /globalworkspace/file3
```

Than for the following input file:

```
 " cd /myworkspace/mydir/myfile1   
   cp -r /myworkspace/mydir/myfile2 /myworkspace/mydir/myfile3 "
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
" cd /myworkspace/globaldir/file1
  cp -r /myworkspace/somedir/file2 /globalworkspace/file3 "
```

What will be a good efficient way to do that?

Comment: `File::Find` is the tool for this job

Comment: @Sobrique: Is it? I don't see any subdirectories involved.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) to handle the absolute paths and path concatenation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Tiny;

my $dir   = shift;
my $input = shift;

my %replace;

opendir my $DIR, $dir or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir $DIR) {
    $file = path($dir)->child($file)->absolute;
    $replace{$file} = readlink $file if -l $file;
}
close $DIR;

my $regex = join '|',
            map quotemeta,                   # To handle filenames containing "." etc.
            sort { length $b <=> length $a } # Not to replace parts of paths (process longer first).
            keys %replace;

open my $IN, '<', $input or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;
    print
}
```